Defining Lie bracket of vector fields along some function
Hello I am struggling with understanding part of this proof.

particularly how you actually can define the Lie bracket of two vector fields along some function. Say we had differentiable function of manifolds $f:A \rightarrow B$ and we had some vector fields $X,Y:A \rightarrow TB$   along $f$ then I don't see how in local coordinates you can actually define the Lie bracket it seems to me like you would run into a situation where you have some object $\frac{\partial X^i(a)}{\partial b_j}$, where $a = (a_0,a_1,..)$ are local coordinates in $A$, $X^i$ some real valued function and $b_j$ local in $B$ and this isn't defined, is there some other approach to define the Lie bracket?

You use the Jacobian. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_bracket_of_vector_fields#In_coordinates

@CyclotomicField I'm familiar with using the Jacobian in local coordinates the case of vector fields on a manifold, but what about vector fields along a function like I described in my question then the dimensions dont line up and $J_X Y$ cant be defined since $J_X$ is a $b*a$ matrix and takes as input $a-$dimensional vectors but $Y$ is $b$ dimensional vector, letting a = dim(A) and b = dim(B)

$d\Phi$ would be a $1$-form with coefficients in $M$ on $(\pm\epsilon)\times I$ and $\partial/\partial s$ a vector field on the same, so $d\Phi(\partial/\partial s)$ is the continuous function $\partial\Phi/\partial s$ from $(\pm\epsilon)\times I\to M$, right, not itself a vector field?
